# Decreasing all values of a dictionary without loop. Or alternative storage possibility

Tags: c#, dictionary, vector, reference, mathnet-numerics

I'm storing some data in a Math.net vector, as I have to do some calculations with it as a whole. This data comes with a time information when it was collected. So for example:

```
Initial = 5, Time 2 = 7, Time 3 = 8, Time 4 = 10
```

So when I store the data in a Vector it looks like this.

```
stateVectorData = [5,7,8,10]
```

Now sometimes I need to extract a single entry of the vector. But I don't have the index itself, but a time Information. So what I try is a dictionary with the information of the time and the index of the data in my stateVector.

```
Dictionary<int, int> stateDictionary = new Dictionary<int, int>(); //Dict(Time, index)
```

Everytime I get new data I add an entry to the dictionary(and of course to the stateVector). So at Time 2 I did:

```
stateDictionary.Add(2,1);
```

Now this works as long as I don't change my vector. Unfortunately I have to delete an entry in the vector when it gets too old. Assume time 2 is too old I delete the second entry and have a resulting vector of:

```
stateVector = [5,8,10]
```

Now my dictionary has the wrong index values stored.
I can think of two possible solutions how to solve this.

1. To loop through the dictionary and decrease every value (with key > 2) by 1.
2. What I think would be more elegant, is storing a reference to an vectorentry in the dictionary instead of the index.

So something like

```
Dictionary<int, ref int> stateDictionary =
    new Dictionary<int, ref int>(); //Dict(Time, reference to vectorentry)
stateDictionary.Add(2, ref stateVector[1]);
```

Using something like this, I wouldn't care about deleting some entrys in the vector, as I still have the reference to the rest of the vectorentries. Now I know it's not possible to store a reference in C#.

So my question is, is there any alternative to looping through the whole dictionary? Or is there another solution without a dictionary I don't see at the moment?

Edit to answer juharr:
Time information doesn't always increase by one. Depends on some parallel running process and how long it takes. Probably increasing between 1 to 3. But also could be more.
There are some values in the vector which never get deleted. I tried to show this with the initial value of 5 which stays in the vector.

Edit 2:
Vector stores at least 5000 to 6000 elements. Maximum is not defined at the moment, as it is restricted by the elements I can handle in real time, so in my case I have about 0.01s to do my further calculations. This is why I search an effective way, so I can increase the number of elements in the vector (or increase the maximum "age" of my vectorentries).
I need the whole vector for calculation about 3 times the number I need to add a value.
I have to delete an entry with the lowest frequency. And finding a single value by its time key will be the most often case. Maybe 30 to 100 times a second.

I know this all sounds very undefined, but the frequency of finding and deleting part depends on an other process, which can vary a lot.

Though hope you can help me. Thanks so far.

Edit 3:
@Robinson
The exact number of times I need the whole vector also depends on the parallel process. Minimum would be two times every iteration (so twice in 0.01s), maximum at least 4 to 6 times every iteration.
Again, the size of the vector is what I want to maximize. So assumed to be very big.

Edit Solution:
First thanks to all, who helped me.
After experimenting a bit, I'm using the following construction.
I'm using a List, where I save the indexes in my state vector.
Additionally I use a Dictionary to assign my Time-key to the List Entry.
So when I delete something in the state vector, I loop only over the List, which seems to be much faster than looping the dictionary.

So it is:

```
stateVectorData = [5,7,8,10]
IndexList = [1,2,3];
stateDictionary = { Time 2, indexInList = 0; Time 3, indexInList = 1; Time 4, indexInList = 2 }
TimeKey->stateDictionary->indexInList -> IndexList -> indexInStateVector -> data
```

Comment: Do the time indexes always start at 1 and increase by 1?  If so why not just use a `List<int>`?

Comment: add a new reference type that holds that value. it can listen to a centralized place that has the modifier.

Comment: What is a typical length of the vector? What is the maximum length? How often are items added to the vector? How often are they removed? How often do you actually need to find an item in the vector by its time value? Depending on the answers to these questions, you might consider getting rid of the dictionary altogether (if you don't use it very often, a linear scan of the vector is probably fine), or just rebuilding it from scratch when the vector changes (if items aren't removed from the vector very often). Unfortunately, there aren't enough details here to know the best answer for you.

Comment: What do you use the vector for and how frequently do you use it?  If you only need it occasionally, dependent upon its size, it may be better just to keep the dictionary and make a vector from it on the fly.    Sometimes doing this kind of thing will be quicker than building a data structure and trying to be "clever" about it.

Comment: Given your realtime requirements, I'd just have a second parallel vector that contained the other half of the data. Any operations that add or remove to one, also add or remove to the other.

Comment: @overslacked : I don't know if I completely understand what you mean. You propose to have another vector containing the time information and when I need a single entry search for that time entry?

Comment: You cant use an array or list for elements in a vector. How will you know if an element is removed which element is what since the index is dictating the element type?

Comment: @Neill
Thats exactly the problem. As soon as I delete an element I only have the time value as a reference which data I'm searching for.  

I will try the version with recreating the vector from the dictionary and compare it to the loop version and a combination, using a vector and a dictionary(key=time, value=data) parallel, choosing the vector when I need it as a whole and the dictionary, when I need a single entry.

Again thank you all so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
public class Vector
{
    private List<int> _timeElements = new List<int>();

    public Vector(int[] times)
    {
        Add(times);
    }

    public void Add(int time)
    {
        _timeElements.Add(time);
    }

    public void Add(int[] times)
    {
        _timeElements.AddRange(time);
    }

    public void Remove(int time)
    {
        _timeElements.Remove(time);
        if (OnRemove != null)
            OnRemove(this, time);
    }

    public List<int> Elements { get { return _timeElements; } }

    public event Action<Vector, int> OnRemove;
}

public class Vectors
{
    private Dictionary<int, List<Vector>> _timeIndex;

    public Vectors(int maxTimeSize)
    {
        _timeIndex = new Dictionary<int, List<Vector>>(maxTimeSize);
        for (var i = 0; i < maxTimeSize; i++)
            _timeIndex.Add(i, new List<Vector>());

        List = new List<Vector>();
    }

    public List<Vector> FindVectorsByTime(int time)
    {
        return _timeIndex[time];
    }

    public List<Vector> List { get; private set; }

    public void Add(Vector vector)
    {
        List.Add(vector);
        vector.Elements.ForEach(element => _timeIndex[element].Add(vector));
            vector.OnRemove += OnRemove;
    }

    private void OnRemove(Vector vector, int time)
    {
        _timeIndex[time].Remove(vector);
    }
}
```

To use:

```
var vectors = new Vectors(maxTimeSize: 6000);

var vector1 = new Vector(new[] { 5, 30, 8, 20 });
var vector2 = new Vector(new[] { 25, 5, 23, 11 });

vectors.Add(vector1);
vectors.Add(vector2);

var findsTwo = vectors.FindVectors(time: 5);

vector1.Remove(time: 5);

var findsOne = vectors.FindVectors(time: 5);
```

The same can be done for adding times, also the code is just for illustration purposes.

Comment: Thanks Neill for the input, after the weekend I've tried it now, but this is not exactly what I was looking for, as I want to use the predefined Math.net Vector class.

Posted the solution, which I'm now using as an edit of the question.